Angularjs Application showing sourceType module error while parsing
I am working on AngularJs 1.x application. I have successfully installed node modules but when I am trying to run the application using command npm run bundle , I am encountering the error which is given below. I checked on various website some suggested to install the packages like browserify and set source type module in parseSection in package.json but none of them worked.
Error

SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (12:0) while parsing /home/username/Project/gl-common-page/login page/signin.js while parsing file: /home/username/Project/gl-common-page/login page/signin.js

Screenshot

signin.js
var global = require('global/window');
var document = require('global/document');
var images = require('./images.json');

import images from './images.json'

var LoginController = global.LoginController || {};

LoginController.getCurrentWeekNumber = function () {
  var currDate  = new Date();
  var currDayNumber = currDate.getDate();
  var currMonth = currDate.getMonth();
  var shift = currMonth * 4;
  var currentWeek = (currDayNumber % 7 === 0) ? currDayNumber / 7 : Math.floor(currDayNumber / 7) + 1;
  return shift + currentWeek;
};

LoginController.getSuitableImage = function (currWeek, imagesLen) {
  if (!currWeek || !imagesLen) throw new Error('getSuitableImage(): all params should be added');
  return currWeek % imagesLen || imagesLen;
};

LoginController.getBackgroundImage = function () {
   var currentWeek = this.getCurrentWeekNumber(), imagesLen = Object.keys(images).length;
   return images[currentWeek] || images[this.getSuitableImage(currentWeek, imagesLen)];
};

LoginController.signInAction = function (user, cb) {
  this._loginEndpoint = '/api/account/login';
  try { var _userJSON = JSON.stringify(user); }
  catch (error) { throw new Error('data can not be processes as JSON'); }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', this._loginEndpoint, true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      return cb(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
    }
  }
  request.send(_userJSON);
};

var LoginView = global.LoginView || {};

LoginView.setup = function (controller) {
  this._controller = controller;

  this.container$ = document.querySelector('.gl-container-fluid');
  this.loginField$ = document.querySelector('.gl-list-item .gl-login-field');
  this.passwordField$ = document.querySelector('.gl-list-item .gl-password-field');

  this.btn$ = document.querySelector('.gl-submit-button');
  return this;
};

LoginView._signIn = function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (!this.loginField$.value || !this.passwordField$.value) return;
  var user = { username: this.loginField$.value, password: this.passwordField$.value };
  this._controller.signInAction(user, function (data) {

  });
};

LoginView._bindControls = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.loginField$.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    self.loginField$ = document.querySelector('.gl-list-item .gl-login-field');
  });
  self.passwordField$.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    self.passwordField$ = document.querySelector('.gl-list-item .gl-password-field');
  });
  return this;
}

LoginView._setBackground = function () {
  this.container$.style.backgroundImage = 'url({{image_url}})'.replace('{{image_url}}', this._controller.getBackgroundImage().login);
  return this;
};

LoginView.render = function () {
  var self = this;
  this._setBackground();
  this._bindControls();
  this.btn$.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    self._signIn.call(self, evt);
  });
  return this;
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (evt) {
  LoginView.setup(LoginController);
  LoginView.render();
});


any solution for this error ?
